# Express4 routing issue

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am currently using router.param() to load a resource instance when a specific param is detected:

**table.route.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import validate from 'express-validation';
import paramValidation from '../../../config/param-validation';
import tableCtrl from '../controllers/table.controller';
const router = express.Router(); 
router.route('/:tableId')
   /** GET /api/tables/:tableId - Get table */
  .get(tableCtrl.get)

  /** PUT /api/tables/:tableId - Update table */
  .put(validate(paramValidation.updateTable), tableCtrl.update)

  /** DELETE /api/tables/:tableId - Delete table */
  .delete(tableCtrl.remove);

/** Load table when API with tableId route parameter is hit */
router.param('tableId', tableCtrl.load);

export default router;
```

**table.controller.js**

```
import Table from '../../models/table.model';
function load(req, res, next, id) {
  Table.get(id)
    .then((table) => {
      req.table = table; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
      return next();
    })
    .catch(e => next(e));
}

function get(req, res) {
  return res.json(req.table);
}
export default { load, get, ... };
```

This work well...  however, I need to add another route to get only the *meta* object from the Table model

**table.model.js**

```
const TableSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  meta: {...},
  columns: [{ ....}]
});
```

So I can add the following route with '*meta*' as a path parameter

```
router.route('/:tableId/meta')
   /** GET /api/tables/:tableId - Get table */
  .get(tableCtrl.get)
```

As 'meta' is a path parameter after the :tableId param, how can I avoid executing the tableCtrl.load function, and rather executing another one like tableCtrl.loadMeta

router.param('tableId', tableCtrl.load);
router.param('tableId/meta', tableCtrl.loadMeta); <= this is wrong of course

thanks for your feedback

**UPDATE 1**

I am trying this way , but maybe there is a better one ?

```
router.param('tableId', (req, res, next) => {
  const path = url.parse(req.originalUrl).pathname;
  const lastpart = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  if (lastpart === 'meta') {
    console.log('GOT IT', lastpart);
    tableCtrl.loadMeta(req, res, next);
  } else {
    tableCtrl.load(req, res, next);
  }
  next();
});
```

**UPDATE 2**. *see robertklepp comment*

Removing next(e); in the router.param() block effectively raises un error

```
1) ## Table APIs # GET /api/v1/tables/:tableId/meta should get table meta:
     TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
      at server/v1/tests/table.test.js:120:18
      at tryCatcher (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
      at Async._drainQueue (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
      at Async._drainQueues (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
```

In ALL routes with the :tableId parameter, the model get id is called twice ... one for :tableId and another one for :tableId/meta

```
    # GET /api/v1/tables/:tableId/meta
    model get id:  58fda13882be03c9999ba7ef
    route param:  meta
    model get id:  58fda13882be03c9999ba7ef
          1) should get table meta
```

something wrong in my table.router.js file, after checking , I can see that I forgot to remove the original router.param() line... see it in the following file

**table.router.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import validate from 'express-validation';
import paramValidation from '../../../config/param-validation';
import tableCtrl from '../controllers/table.controller';

const url = require('url');

const router = express.Router(); // eslint-disable-line new-cap

router.route('/')
   /** GET /api/tables - Get list of tables */
  .get(tableCtrl.list)

  /** POST /api/tables - Create new table */
  .post(validate(paramValidation.createTable), tableCtrl.create);

router.route('/meta')
/** GET /api/tables - Get list of all tables meta */
  .get(tableCtrl.list);

router.route('/columns')
/** GET /api/tables - Get list of all tables meta */
  .get(tableCtrl.list);

router.route('/:tableId/meta')
  /** GET /api/tables/meta - Get table meta */
  .get(tableCtrl.get);

router.route('/:tableId/columns')
/** GET /api/tables/meta - Get table meta */
  .get(tableCtrl.get);

router.route('/:tableId')
   /** GET /api/tables/:tableId - Get full table */
  .get(tableCtrl.get)

  /** PUT /api/tables/:tableId - Update full table */
  .put(validate(paramValidation.updateTable), tableCtrl.update)

  /** DELETE /api/tables/:tableId - Delete full table */
  .delete(tableCtrl.remove);

/** Load table when API with tableId route parameter is hit */
router.param('tableId', tableCtrl.load); <===== SHOULD BE DELETED !!

router.param('tableId', (req, res, next, tableId) => {
  const path = url.parse(req.originalUrl).pathname;
  const lastpart = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  if (lastpart === 'meta') {
    console.log('route param: ', lastpart);
    tableCtrl.loadMeta(req, res, next, tableId);
  } else if (lastpart === 'columns') {
    console.log('route param: ', lastpart);
    tableCtrl.loadColumns(req, res, next, tableId);
  } else {
    console.log('route param: ', lastpart);
    tableCtrl.load(req, res, next, tableId);
  }
  // next();
});

export default router;
```

Comment: I don't think there's a better way. FWIW, you should remove the last `next()` call, `next` is already being called by the database operations.

Comment: thanks for your feedback... it's up & running well 
FYI , removing next() is raising an error :

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: If it stops running well, remember my comment ;D `next` should be called just once, your code is calling it twice. The error that you're getting may be getting obscured by calling it twice, so you should really look into that. It could also be that the route handlers that use `:tableId` actually get called _twice_ for each request.

Comment: Found the duplicated router.param() line in my router file , see UPDATE 2... thanks again for your help ...